# Javafx listview dynamically changing the color of listview cells

Tags: css, listview, javafx, fxml

Hello I'm currently building project that uses javaFx and was wondering if it's possible to dynamically change the color of a listview objects cells at run-time. Each cell of the listview represents an object which has a color associated with it. The issue I'm having is that each object has a color that's generated at run time and the number of objects won't necessarily remain constant.

The underlying GUI that the javaFX code base is working with is fxml. I've tried looking into using CSS but since the amount of objects and color associated with those objects is generated at run-time I can't hard code it into a style-sheet. I've also been looking to using cell factories to create the desired cell for each cell, but I need to color to be passed into the cell factory and it has to be in the RGB format. Does anyone have any experience with a problem such as this one?

for(int i =0; i< mice.mice.size();i++){

```
selectedMiceListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Object>, 
ListCell<Object>>() {

         // @Override
                        public ListCell<Object> call(final ListView<Object> param) {
                            final ListCell<Object> cell = new ListCell<Object>() {

                                @Override
                                protected void updateItem(final Object item, final boolean empty) {
                                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(" + mice.mice.get(i).red + "," + mice.mice.get(i).green + ", " + mice.mice.get(i).blue + ");");

                                }
                            };
                            return cell;
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Below is what I've tried so far, it says that inner classes must effectively have final variables. Is there a way to modify it so that it accepts the rgb value i'm trying to set it too?

Comment: Try to ask a specific question and provide what you have done so far. SO is not a code writing website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the below code paints every cell in the listview with black

```
 this.listView
    .setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Object>, ListCell<Object>>() {

      @Override
      public ListCell<Object> call(final ListView<Object> param) {
        final ListCell<Object> cell = new ListCell<Object>() {

          @Override
          protected void updateItem(final Object item, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(100, 150, 200), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

          }
        };
        return cell;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can this be modified so that the set style method can take different rgb values?